# how to set different layouts in a cardview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am trying to make a card view like bellow

```
+----------------------------+
|[icon1]   text 1            |
|  ▼                   text3 |
|[icon2]   text 2            |
+----------------------------+
```

How can I create a card like this?
I tried to use 2 different layout inside a cardView but its overlapped by one another.

Comment: can you share your XML code here

Comment: ConstraintLayout is what you need. Here's a tutorial: https://medium.com/@eugenebrusov/using-of-constraintlayout-to-build-out-cardview-with-material-design-e111e64575c2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at CardView's docs you will see that it extends FrameLayout, because of this if you have several children in it they will overlap. What you need to do is have a single layout as the direct child of CardView, let's say ConstraintLayout, and inside this ConstraintLayout you set as many child views as you want.

So this code...

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img1"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img2"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/img1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                android:text="Hello"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/img1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/img1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/img1"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv2"
                android:text="World"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/img2"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/img2"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/img2"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv3"
                android:text="Hello World!"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"/>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Would produce this:[image]